# A short command to clear the current line?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I want to clear a line in `vim` rather than delete it.

Before:

```
foo
bar
lineToClear
baz
```

After

```
foo
bar

baz
```

Of the `vim` commands I know, the closest I can get to this is `D` (upper case d), but usually this requires me to type `0` first to go to the beginning of the line.

I know, I'm lazy.

Does there exist a command that just clears the entire line, not just the characters after the cursor?

Maybe some sort of [*Containment*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007264H36)-esque type of direct brain interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `S`. It clears the line, then puts you into insert mode. If you don't want to do insert mode, `0D` will be the quickest command set.

As glts mentioned, you can create a custom mapping by running one of the following commands. The first argument (S/D) can be changed to whatever you'd like.

```
:nnoremap S S<Esc>
```

or

```
:nnoremap D 0D
```

[Reference](http://www.worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html)

Comment: Yup, and since you didn't use `S` before, @CoryKlein, you can remap it to only clear the line: `:nnoremap S S<Esc>`.

Comment: `S` is definitely a good option, but FWIW I actually already knew about it. I didn't mention it in my question because `D` is already more efficient in the average case - it sometimes only requires one key stroke, where `S` is guaranteed to require two in the "only clear a line use case" due to the requirement to hit `Ctrl-C` or `ESC` afterwards.

Comment: Well there you go, @CoryKlein, you can't get any more efficient than that. Only personal mappings can bring further optimization (because no such "clear the line" command exists in Vim).

Comment: @glts And that is exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: personally I don't recommend the two mappings in the answer. because, with it, one day you will come to post another question, how to delete text after the cursor in current line. or how to del whole line, and switch to insert mode, ready to insert new text.

Comment: Right, which is why I include that the first argument can be something else (not necessarily S or D)

Comment: Also - key mappings don't have to be permanent. If you are editing a file that requires a specific command a lot, simple make a mapping right there and don't bother putting it in your `.vimrc`. I think it is worthwhile to point out that you can map the command to make it faster.

Answer (score -1):

There is a slightly better way than `0D`.  It is still two keys, but does not require `shift` or going all the way up to the top row to press `0`:

Simply just:

```
dd
```

Comment: `dd` was my first thought, too. However, Cory said "Sometimes I want to **clear** a line in vim _rather than_ delete it."